# Using tic/toc functions instead of a timer

Tags: matlab, timer, counter

Using `timer` objects gets too complicated especially when you have to use more than one timer so I was trying to think of alternative approaches.

I want to avoid using `pause`, since it stops other functions from executing. I thought of using the `tic` `toc` functions to measure elapsed time but the code I have written below does not work as I expect.

```
time=tic;
if(abs(toc(time)))==3 %% if 3 second past
    my function
end
```

How can I modify this code so that it executes the command after 3 seconds?

Comment: Please tag the language. I'm assuming Ruby?

Comment: MATLAB, sorry i always forget that this is not a matlab forum

Comment: For future reference, don't put the language in the title, it adds unnecessary bulk. Put it as a tag as you did with "timer" and "counter".

Comment: You should really use `timer` objects to do this correctly *especially* if you need multiple ones to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TLDR;

A `tic`/`toc` pair and a `while` loop is literally no different than using `pause` since they both block execution of any other functions. You have to use `timer` objects.

#### A More Detailed Explanation

In order to make this work, you'd need to use a `while` loop to monitor if the required amount of time has passed. Also, you'll want to use `<` to check if the time has elapsed because the loop condition isn't guaranteed to be evaluated every femtosecond and therefore it's never going to be *exact*.

```
function wait(time_in_sec)
    tic
    while toc < time_in_sec
    end

    % Do thing after 3 seconds
    fprintf('Has been %d seconds!\n', time_in_sec)
end
```

The unfortunate thing about a `while` loop approach is that it prevents you from running multiple "timers" at once. For example, in the following case, it will wait 3 seconds for the first task and then wait 5 seconds for the second task requiring a total time or 8 seconds.

```
wait(3)
wait(5)
```

Also, while the `while` loop is running, *nothing* else will be able to execute within MATLAB.

A much better approach is to setup multiple `timer` objects and configure them with callbacks so that they can run at the same time and they will not block any operations within MATLAB while they run. When you need multiple timer objects (which you consider to be a pain) is *exactly* when you *have* to use `timer` objects. 
If it's really that cumbersome, write your own function which does all of the boilerplate stuff for you

```
function tmr = wait(time_in_sec)
    tmr = timer('StartDelay',       time_in_sec, ...
                'ExecutionMode',    'SingleShot', ...
                'TimerFcn',         @(s,e)status(time_in_sec));
    tmr.start()

    function status(t)
        fprintf('Has been %d seconds!\n', t);
    end
end

wait(3)
wait(5)     % Both will execute after 5 seconds
```

Also since the timers are non-blocking (when the callback isn't running), I can execute commands immediately after starting the timers

```
wait(3)
disp('Started 3 second timer')
wait(5)
disp('Started 5 second timer')
```

If you try this with your while loop, you'll see the `while` loop's blocking behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you need a while loop or something to wait for time to be 3 seconds.
something like this

```
time=tic;
while 1
    if(abs(toc(time)))==3 %% if 3 second past
        my function
        break;
    end
end
```

If you want to call `my function` every 3 seconds, then you should do something like this:

```
time=tic;
while 1
    if mod((abs(toc(time))),3) == 0 %% if 3 second past
        my function
    end
end
```

Please make sure that you have some way of telling once you are done and then break the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it to >= instead of ==. That will catch it if it misses the exact value.